# Recover unpushed commits from master

Tags: git, bitbucket

By mistakenlly I committed some code to master and pushed it. But suddenly I lost the network connection, and the push was not successful. Then I undo my last commit, then I got the first commit instead of my last commit, I have read and tried different ways, but it has not helped. I tried

```
$ git reflog
```

too, but it does not show the commit
How to recover my lost commit? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

here is my reflog result

```
484b79a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, new-branch) HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD
484b79a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, new-branch) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from new-branch to master
484b79a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, new-branch) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to new-branch
484b79a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, new-branch) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to master
484b79a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, new-branch) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from f7ad680230740a053725d57c6a794eea01a471a4 to master
f7ad680 (develop) HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from a4b9b204c9eeb53c851ed29562a4075321cfad7e to HEAD@{10}
a4b9b20 HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from master to HEAD@{10}
484b79a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, new-branch) HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master-recovery to master
267ef22 (master-recovery) HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from master to master-recovery
484b79a (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, new-branch) HEAD@{9}: pull: Fast-forward
a4b9b20 HEAD@{10}: reset: moving to origin/master
f7ad680 (develop) HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from develop to master
f7ad680 (develop) HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from master to develop
f7ad680 (develop) HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from master to master
f7ad680 (develop) HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from master to master
f7ad680 (develop) HEAD@{15}: reset: moving to HEAD
f7ad680 (develop) HEAD@{16}: reset: moving to HEAD~
a4b9b20 HEAD@{17}: clone: from https: my repo
```

Comment: `Then I undo my last commit` ... how exactly did you "undo" your last commit?

Comment: I am using vs-code for coding. there is an option to undo last commit on the source control section in vs-code. I used that option to undo the last commit

Comment: The commit in question should be in the reflog.  Check again.

Comment: Edited the question by adding the output of reflog

Comment: I do not know what vs-code means with "undo a commit", but if it is now dangling, you should see it with `git fsck`,